# Firmware Update for Samsung S LCD I 9003 stops at "preparing firmware update"

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, updates, samsung-kies

I am trying to upgrade the firmware of samsung galaxy S LCD using Samsung Kies. I am using the recent version of Kies. But during when I click start update it is showing that the FirmwareUpdate has stopped working. and it is showing preparing firmware upgrade components forever. Please advice me what to do.

Comment: Have you attempted the update multiple times?

Comment: We've had multiple questions about updates with Samsung Kies. Have you already checked the questions tagged with [tag:samsung-kies]?

Comment: actually I have read some. But some of them are suggesting update through Odin rather than Kies. I read in forums that some of this Odin updates are creating issues with camera and audio. That's why I tried to update through Kies. I am using the latest version of Kies and upon connecting the phone it pops up a firmware update message. So I have tried many times and it is always showing the same error. Now I think it may be a problem with Windows 7? can I update it in Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same problem and just received the following message from Samsung:

> The Kies software does not detect the handsets, there are several
> causes for this and a process of checks will discover the cause and
> show the solution:
>
> 1. Check the system specification is correct for
>    the KIES software.
> 2. Check the correct and up to date version of the
>    software is being used.
> 3. Check that handset is set on the correct mode which is SAMSUNG Kies.
> 4. Be sure that the handset show connected ‘not connecting’ on home screen.
> 5. Try to test a different USB port and restart PC.
> 6. Check in device manager that the driver has been installed and update if required
> 7. If handset has device manager (download one from market place for android 2.1 or higher)
>    ensure that all tasks have been ended and handset is in the idle mode
>    before connecting ‘download the task killer, it is an application used
>    to close all the applications (not just minimizing them)’
> 8. Completely remove current version of the Kies software and re-install
>    the latest version from the website.
> 9. Test with different PC.

It's quite a number of possibilities being mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem.

Open the App Drawer, tap on Settings > Storage, tap on *Unmount SD card*

Then you have to physically remove the SD card. Worked now!

Comment: yeah okay..Actually I have asked it in 2011. Anyway now also I am using the same phone and running on custom firmware now :)